# Injective function $h:A\times C→B\times D$

Tags: logic

Let $f:A→B,\;g:C→D$ be functions.
Prove that if $f, g$ are injective, there's a function $h:A\times C→B\times D$, that is also injective.

How do I prove it?
I started by saying that $f(x)=x$, and $g(x)=x+1$ (so they are injective)
but how do I continue?

Comment: Where did $D$ come from?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily check the function $h$, also denoted $f\times g$
\begin{align}
h:A\times C&\longrightarrow B\times D, \\
(x,y)&\longmapsto \bigl(f(x),g(y)\bigr),
\end{align}
is injective.